# Google BigQuery query to generate each day between startDate and endDate. From that count the rows if no rows count as 0

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data with name(String), createdAt(Timestamp).

I have 2 input which is startDate(2021-01-01) and endDate(2021-01-04)

Date | Count(*)

```
2021-01-01 | 1
2021-01-02 | 0
2021-01-03 | 2
2021-01-04 | 4
```

What I am doing is that I use some a query like this to get all the count

```
SELECT DATE(createdAT), count(*)
FROM  myProject
WHERE DATE(createdAT) <= endDate AND DATE(createdAT) >= startDate
GROUP BY DATE(createdAT)
```

This will give back.

```
2021-01-01 | 1
2021-01-03 | 2
2021-01-04 | 4
```

And then I process to add "2021-01-02 | 0" in the backend code

```
2021-01-01 | 1
2021-01-02 | 0
2021-01-03 | 2
2021-01-04 | 4
```

Is there a query that can handle this logic without doing it in the backend

Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `generate_date_array` function which returns an array of all the dates between your `start_date` and `end_date`.

In your study, you can do everything with the unique following query:

```
SELECT
  dates,
  COUNT(createdAt) AS event_count
FROM
  UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)) dates
LEFT JOIN
  `project.dataset.table` s
ON
  dates = DATE(s.createdAt)
GROUP BY
  dates
```